# Where should I use ParseFloat or Number functions in my code to change my geojson data?

Tags: string, leaflet, parsefloat

*Editing for specificity*

The data in my geojson is formatted as string variables and I need to change those fields to numbers so my legend on my choropleth will read the data. I'm struggling to figure out where to use either the ParseFloat or Number functions so my leaflet map reads the data as a number.

I'm attempting to map each feature using different buttons. One button to show Population, another to show Average Water Bill, etc. I want the legend to show the data called on for each button. Below is the code I have for the legend and for the buttons...

```
    // Global variables
let map;
let lat = 34;
let lon = -118;
let zl = 9;

let geojsonPath = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LCIWaterProjects/DRAFT-LA-County-Governance-Map/main/data/Data_Update.geojson';
let geojson_data;
let geojson_layer;

let brew = new classyBrew();
let legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
let info_panel = L.control();

let fieldtomap;

// initialize+
$( document ).ready(function() {
    createMap(lat,lon,zl);
    getGeoJSON();
});

// create the map
function createMap(lat,lon,zl){
    map = L.map('map').setView([lat,lon], zl);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}',
    {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'light-v10',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FyYWhwZXJlejEiLCJhIjoiY2t0MG9hZDNnMDZ2NDJ1c2M5dzBmb201OSJ9.5fv8NqX5cfA0NMcmEW_63g'
    }).addTo(map);

}

// function to get the geojson data
    $.getJSON(geojsonPath,function(data){
        console.log(data)

        // put the data in a global variable
        geojson_data = data;

        // call the map function
        mapGeoJSON();
    })

function mapGeoJSON(field,num_classes,color,scheme){

    // clear layers in case it has been mapped already
    if (geojson_layer){
        geojson_layer.clearLayers()
    }
    
    // globalize the field to map
    fieldtomap = field;
...
function createLegend(){
    legend.onAdd = function (map) {
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        breaks = brew.getBreaks(),
        labels = [],
        from, to;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < breaks.length; i++) {
            from = breaks[i];
            to = breaks[i + 1];
            if(to) {
                labels.push(
                    '<i style="background:' + brew.getColorInRange(to) + '"></i> ' +
                    from.toFixed(0) + ' &ndash; ' + to.toFixed(0));
                }
            }
            
            div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
            return div;
        };
        
        legend.addTo(map);

// create buttons function
function myPopFunction(){
    mapGeoJSON('Population',5,'YlOrRd','jenks');}

function myServeFunction(){
    mapGeoJSON('Service_Co',5,'BuPu','quantiles');}
```

Comment: That geojson dataset has several numeric properties for each feature. You'll have to be more specific about how you're building (or want to build) that legend.

Comment: Justed edited the question to add some more specificity! Thanks for the feedback.